# How to create a matrix/data frame from a high number of single objects by using a loop?

Tags: r

I have a high number of single objects each one containing a mean value for a year. They are called cddmean1950, cddmean1951, ... ,cddmean2019.

Now I would like to put them together into a matrix or data frame with the first column being the year (1950 - 2019) and the second column being the single mean values.

This is a very long way to do it without looping:

```
matrix <- rbind(cddmean1950,cddmean1951,cddmean1952,...,cddmean2019)
```

Afterwards you transform the matrix to a data frame, create a vector with the years and add it to the data frame.

I am sure there must be a smarter and faster way to do this by using a loop or anything else?

Comment: Take a look at the `get` function. If all your objects are named consistently you could do something like `get(paste0("cddmean", i))` in a loop

Comment: `get` will just grab the object from your environment, then you can bind them or something else from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could be an easy way to do it. Provided all those single objects are in your current environment.

First we would create a list of the variable names using the paste0 function

```
YearRange <- 1950:2019
ObjectName <- paste0("cddmean", YearRange)
```

Then we can use lapply and get to get the values of all these variables as a list.
Then using do.call and rbind we can rbind all these values into a single vector and then finally create your dataframe as you requested.

```
ListofSingleObjects <- lapply(ObjectName, get)
MeanValues <- do.call(rbind,ListofSingleObjects)
df <- data.frame( year = YearRange , Mean = MeanValues )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the job perfectly!
Very nice way of explaining.